# Optional Chaining with different objects

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning about optional and I couldn't find an example about: how to chain optionals from different objects.

My code:

```
let apiKey = "MY_SECRET_API_KEY"

let baseURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/\(apiKey)/")

if  let forecastURL = NSURL(string: "41.155099,-8.678774", relativeToURL: baseURL){
    if let weatherData = NSData(contentsOfURL: forecastURL, options: nil, error: nil){
        if let json = NSString(data: weatherData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
            println(json)
        }

    }
}
```

I don't want to use the `!` in my code, only a matter of readability. How can I code something like this pseudocode :

```
if forecast = ... && weatherData=... && json=...{
    println(json)
}
```

If you think that I should stick with the `!`, I'm open to learn about its advantages.

Comment: This is not possible in the current version of Swift. File a feature request at Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following coding style:

```
let apiKey = "MY_SECRET_API_KEY"

let baseURL: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/\(apiKey)/")
if baseURL == nil {
    // handle error
    return /*error*/
}

let forecastURL: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "41.155099,-8.678774", relativeToURL: baseURL)
if forecastURL == nil {
    // handle error
}

let weatherData: NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: forecastURL, options: nil, error: nil)
if weatherData == nil {
    // handle error
}

let json: NSString! = NSString(data: weatherData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
if json == nil {
    // handle error
}

println(json)
```

It might look verbose, but it keeps indentation level, it "scales" to multiple statements and it's quite readable in my opinion.

If you're sure that some error won't happen, you can skip error handling.

Comment: conditionally unwrapping is the usual way to do this, not implicitly unwrapping them and checking them for nil.

Comment: It increases indentation level for each error check and error handling is far away from error source which makes code hard to read and understand. I'm talking about situations where optionals are used to handle errors.

Comment: There are constructs that allow a more functional approaches to these issues, rather than trying to do the same thing in Swift that one used to do in Objective-C. For example:  http://robots.thoughtbot.com/efficient-json-in-swift-with-functional-concepts-and-generics